# Description of the "disciplined" badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, disciplined-badge

Supposedly, the **Disciplined** badge is awarded [if](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) one,

> Deleted own post with 3 or more upvotes.

Today I was awarded this badge, without deleting any post myself. However, some question (I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363397)...) to which I posted an answer with four upvotes, was deleted *by someone else*. I don't think that I should have received the badge, since it was not me who was disciplined (somebody else made the call).

One could also argue that this is intended behavior, but in that case the badge description should be updated.

***Update***: Three hours ago Jeff tagged this as `status-norepo`. Then Shog9 [tossed in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19617/description-of-the-disciplined-badge/23562#23562) an hypothesis. Perhaps we *can* reproduce this behavior by following the steps outlined in that post. (Or somebody could just check the source code, but where's the fun in that?!)

Comment: You were disciplined :P

Answer (score 23):

You are disciplined enough to post here saying that you got a badge you didn't deserve. The Stack Overflow system is intelligent enough to know  that you *would* do this, so it awarded you the badge in advance.

Comment: Hahah well put.

Comment: Queue Skynet reference.

Comment: In that case, the badge description should *still* be updated to read: "This badge is awarded to users who will complain about getting this badge".

Answer (score 12):

According to the revision history, you deleted and then undeleted that answer prior to the question itself being deleted.

I've seen this before: when the answers for a question are deleted *en masse*, the deletion timestamp is set to the actual time of deletion... but for previously-deleted answers, the "deleted by" attribute isn't reset - it will still reflect the last user to have deleted that specific answer.

It appears that this is enough to trigger the Disciplined badge...

Comment: I completely forgot about temporarily deleting the answer myself. You may be on to something here. Plus, your hypothesis is easily testable.

Comment: Yesterday it happened the same to me.

Answer (score 1):

I am led to believe that the algorithm is not at all checking who deleted, merely that it was deleted and it met score requirements.

I think the code needs to be updated. I don't see why one should get a badge when someone else deletes it.

Comment: Go update it then

Comment: Um...this diamond on my name didn't give me access to their SVN and a paycheck.

Comment: You have pony power.

Comment: no, it is checking, there's something odd about the revision history in this case.