# Are answers that are deleted to gain a "Disciplined Badge" monitored or moderated?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers, disciplined-badge

I discovered [the *Disciplined* badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined) -- which you get by deleting your own post with score of 3 or higher. And, I've gone through [What is the purpose of the "disciplined" badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7609/178505) and [Description of the "disciplined" badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19617/178505).

Might some people delete good answers to get this badge? Is there a system or group of moderators which checks when answers, having more than a 3 score, are deleted -- especially if a badge-reward results?  (IE: "Gaming the *Disciplined* badge")

Update:
I am not saying to remove this badge. I just wanted to know if there is a system or moderation tracking deleted answers having 3 or more score.

Comment: You completely changed the meaning of your question... don't do that.

Comment: Actually I asked 2 questions under same title. But then I got to know my second question is my actual question. And people assuming different question. Ist question is pointing to 2nd question. But people may assume different views that title. That's why I have changed my title. Isn't that fair?

Comment: There are those who get it naturally by *being* disciplined (deleting an outdated or wrong but upvoted answer), and those who just want the badge, who can undelete their post again right after getting the badge.

Comment: Does badge retain after undeleting post. What's purpose of that badge then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cheated on the Disciplined badge, how bad is it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95918/i-cheated-on-the-disciplined-badge-how-bad-is-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there is no direct system for checking answers with 3 or more upvotes that get deleted.  I'm guessing that there shouldn't be such a system either; do you have evidence of a problem?

Sometimes users will delete their posts in a snit.  This is usually caught by [the super-secret vandalism flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94421/148310).

Most of the time, when a user deletes an upvoted answer, it is just out of embarrassment, when they've posted incorrect or incomplete info that got upvoted while someone else posted a better or more complete answer.  So, the question and community loses nothing.

However, there ***are*** mechanisms to detect and reverse less-than-honorable deletions:

1. The aforementioned vandalism flag.
2. Moderators can see deleted answers and undelete them if they feel it is warranted.
3. High-reputation users can also see deleted answers ([10K rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)) and flag them for undeletion.  Or, sometimes directly vote to undelete them ([20K rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user)).
4. If you are a low rep user, and you know that a valuable answer was deleted, flag the question and/or post here on meta about the deleted answer.  It will get straightened out if warranted.

Comment: That sounds good...

Comment: If someone founded post deleted was useful and wanted to undelete. And undeleted it. Then does badge revoked or not?

Comment: As near as I can tell, [the badge does not automatically get revoked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68267/148310).  If you spot someone gaming the system like that, bring it up here on meta.

Comment: Confirmed on one of my accounts.  [It is still possible to game this badge, quite easily](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95918/148310).

Answer (score 7):

If you have posted an answer almost identical to somebody else's that was posted at the same time and their answer is accepted over yours, then I can see the reasoning for deleting your own answer, even if it is up voted.

Even though your answer is perfectly good, it is now just a repetition of the accepted answer and adds no value to SO. Hence, the `disciplined` thing to do is to delete your post to remove the 'noise'.

If your answer contains some extra, valid information then the ultra-disciplined thing to do is to edit that information into the accepted answer.

I think such `discipline` deserves a badge.

So, in this case the good answer has not been lost, but possibly made slightly better. I imagine the `Disciplined` badge was created to encourage just this type of behaviour.

I'm not a moderator, so I can't offer an answer on the second part of your question.

Comment: I know reasons for disciplined badge. Does any system or moderators checks this answer is deleted is good or bad. So community shouldn't lose good answers.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Well it's hard to answer a question accurately when it gets a major edit after you've answered it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no system that triggers on a single deleted answer, of which I am aware, but there are moderator tools that show us when a user has deleted larger numbers of their own posts, regardless of their scores.

The thinking being that if someone is just deleting one or two posts, they must have a reason for it. No sense throwing up lots of moderator noise for that sort of thing. But if they are deleting multiple things, that could be a problem.