# Getting Disciplined badge when you helped to remove the question containing own answer?

Tags: support, disciplined-badge

I recently helped to delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057241/pdo-prepare-stopped-the-function-from-working) in which I had an answer with 4 upvotes. Once it was deleted I lost the gained rep, but no Disciplined badge was awarded.

One could argue that it's not strictly a removal, because I've migrated my answer to [its duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057020/having-trouble-getting-my-prepared-statement-to-work/15057504#15057504) and coincidentally gained the same amount of up- and downvotes :)

Though, according to [this old meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19617/description-of-the-disciplined-badge) it would seem that when questions containing your answer are deleted you're indeed eligible for the badge.

I've waited the recommended 24 hours :) Did I miss something obvious?

**Update**

Okay, I did miss something obvious as it turned out. The user from the aforementioned question had temporarily deleted their answer, thereby "illegally" obtaining the badge before reinstating it.

Though, could this then be a feature request perhaps? If you helped to delete a question where your own answer has 3+ votes, you would get it? =D =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "disciplined" badge description says:

> Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher.

[One answer to the meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23562/159834) you linked states that the OP deleted his own post, then undeleted it, which managed to trigger the badge being awarded, and apparently that is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

According to the rules, you would have had to delete your own answer to be awarded the badge (not just participate in deleting the question you answered). Anything else should be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks. It somehow didn't occur to me that it was "wrongly" awarded for that user.

Comment: The [highest voted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19628/159834) was a joke answer. It's not clear whether or not the "bug" persists.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that answer was a joke ;-)

Comment: TBH I think this would make a great badge as well, deleting posts you gained a lot of rep from. Sometimes the rep-hugging makes people not do the right thing.

Comment: I've updated my question to suggest that. Should I retag it as feature-request?

Comment: I would make a new post, but it's up to you. I would think it would be a different badge though, not just a new way to gain the "disciplined" one.

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169060/helping-to-delete-question-where-own-answer-gained-3-rep). And thanks again!