# Helping to delete question where own answer gained >= X votes

Tags: discussion, badge-request

This is related to my [earlier post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169054/getting-disciplined-badge-when-you-helped-to-remove-the-question-containing-own) here and inspired by [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169056/184077).

> Could there be a badge for helping to delete a question wherein your own (non-wiki) answer has gained a certain amount (tbd) of upvotes? A question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057241/pdo-prepare-stopped-the-function-from-working) for instance.

It's closely associated with the Disciplined badge, and having this badge may incentivise users to delete a question in which they have a rep stake when there's a better duplicate for instance, instead of resisting in fear of losing rep or unwillingness to do so.

On the other hand, the badge may invite an unwanted type of behaviour; the one where gaining the badge is the only motivation:

1. Find stupid question,
2. Write hilarious answer, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/1338292) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1576009/1338292),
3. Wait for the votes on your answer to reach past a certain point,
4. Vote to close (if not closed yet), followed by vote to delete; other high-rep users will agree with the decision to delete anyway.

Idea on how to curb that problem are welcome. You would expect better behaviour from 10k+ users, though with badge fever you can never really be certain of that.

Comment: I've actually wanted to do this a number of times. While clearing out some of my old useless answers, I find that a lot of the times, the question sucks even more than my answer. And I wanna just nuke the entire question along with my answer.

Comment: Turns out I'd have four of these badges. [I'm not sure that's a good thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576003/how-long-does-it-take-to-read-a-750-pages-book)

Comment: @Shog9 I've expanded the rules to exclude wiki answers :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem I have with this badge proposal is that it could also lead people to answer questions that they know *should* be closed/deleted (kind of like what you did), which I don't believe behavior that should be encouraged.

However, I think this has merit for older questions, especially ones with a huge amount of upvotes, as people tend to engage in "rep-hugging", fighting for a question to stay alive just because they gained some rep from it. But, I think that's too niche of a situation to merit creating a new badge, especially since voting to delete already requires a substantial amount of rep and is not a feature that most users have access to.

Comment: In my own defence, my answer was not given knowing that there was already a dupe :) however, if I wrote an answer off the cuff and then later find a better dupe myself and then have it removed .. should that not be rewarded? :)

Comment: @Jack I didn't mean to pick on you (bad example, really), but surely you know what I'm talking about. I can totally see people answering crap just for the badge. Badges (or hats, or whatever) affect behavior in a major way, sometimes it's hard to predict the side effects. I'm not against the idea, I just think it needs to be done carefully, and that doing so might make it too complicated.

Comment: Another thing to note is that "old rep" doesn't go away when a question is deleted. I forget the details, but I think it's something like if the post is over X months old and has 3 or more upvotes, you keep the rep. Still, there's more to it than rep points. I still fear how this would affect new questions, I can totally see people posting answers when they shouldn't to get the badge, even though they'd have to be higher rep members (in order to be able to delete).

Comment: I think that's a fair point, +1.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this would help nudge people who throw out those crappy "you're missing a semicolon" answers on *too localized* questions, knowing full-well they'll get smothered with upvotes. Maybe if there's a badge there, they'll finally stop thinking about the reputation (that they'll inevitably lose anyways) and start thinking about keeping the site clean and vote to close/delete (because most of them never do). Not claiming they're *all* after the reputation, but it irritates me sometimes to see users who can vote to close just throw out an answer and leave the crappy question sitting there.